# issue in making Queue data structure as array implementation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, data-structures, queue

this code to make simple queue data structure as array implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define Q_MAX_SIZE 255
#include <stdbool.h>
struct queue
{
    int* pointer;
    int* currentValue;
    int max, count, theQueue[Q_MAX_SIZE];
};

void initQueue(struct queue*);
bool pushQueue(struct queue*, int);
int* popQueue(struct queue*);

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, num = 0;
    struct queue obj[5];

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        initQueue(&obj[i]);

        for(j = 0; j<3; j++)
        {
            num++;
            pushQueue(&obj[i], num);
        }
        num = 0;
    }

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("Queue[%d]:\n", i);
        int* inputobj;
        inputobj = popQueue(&obj[i]);

        while(inputobj != NULL)
        {
            printf("Queue[No.%d] = %d\n", i, *inputobj);
            inputobj = popQueue(&obj[i]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    puts("done..!");

    return 0;
}

//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

void initQueue(struct queue *Q)
{
    Q->pointer = Q->theQueue;
    Q->max = Q_MAX_SIZE;
    Q->count = 0;
}

bool pushQueue(struct queue *Q, int input)
{
    if(Q->count < Q->max)
    {
        *Q->pointer = input;
        Q->pointer++;
        Q->count++;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

int* popQueue(struct queue *Q)
{
    int i;
    if(Q->count > 0)
    {
        Q->currentValue = Q->theQueue;
        Q->pointer--;
        Q->count--;

        for(i=0; i < Q->count; i++)
        {
            int* currentPtr = Q->theQueue + i;
            int* nextPtr = currentPtr + 1;
            *currentPtr = *nextPtr;
        }
        return Q->currentValue;
    }

    else
        NULL;
}
```

there is a problem with the code in the function `popQueue()` in this line:

`Q->currentValue = Q->theQueue;`

it is work put the output is not correct

```
output:
Queue[0]:
Queue[No.0] = 2
Queue[No.0] = 3
Queue[No.0] = 3

Queue[1]:
Queue[No.1] = 2
Queue[No.1] = 3
Queue[No.1] = 3

Queue[2]:
Queue[No.2] = 2
Queue[No.2] = 3
Queue[No.2] = 3

Queue[3]:
Queue[No.3] = 2
Queue[No.3] = 3
Queue[No.3] = 3

Queue[4]:
Queue[No.4] = 2
Queue[No.4] = 3
Queue[No.4] = 3

done..!
```

but after i change the pointer (`currentValue`) in the `queue` struct to make it of type integer and edit some lines in the function `popQueue()` every thing work fine.

**--here is the function after editing:**

```
int* popQueue(struct queue *Q)
{
  int i;
  if(Q->count > 0)
  {
    Q->currentValue = Q->theQueue[0];
    Q->pointer--;
    Q->count--;

    for(i=0; i < Q->count; i++)
    {
      int* currentPtr = Q->theQueue + i;
      int* nextPtr = currentPtr + 1;
      *currentPtr = *nextPtr;
    }
    return &Q->currentValue;
  }
```

-- and this is the correct output:

```
Queue[0]:
Queue[No.0] = 1
Queue[No.0] = 2
Queue[No.0] = 3

Queue[1]:
Queue[No.1] = 1
Queue[No.1] = 2
Queue[No.1] = 3

Queue[2]:
Queue[No.2] = 1
Queue[No.2] = 2
Queue[No.2] = 3

Queue[3]:
Queue[No.3] = 1
Queue[No.3] = 2
Queue[No.3] = 3

Queue[4]:
Queue[No.4] = 1
Queue[No.4] = 2
Queue[No.4] = 3
```

### The Question is: what makes the first code provide wrong output?

Comment: Did this compile without warnings when all warnings were turned on?

Comment: i compile it with gcc using code::block IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What gave you the wrong output in the first case was the fact that the pointer `Q->currentValue` never changed its value (the address which it was holding). It was always pointing to the first element in the queue.

Say the queue contained `{1, 2, 3 |,<garbage>}`.

That means, that after the first pop, the queue became:

`{2, 3 |, 3, <garbage>}`

and `currentValue` still held the address of the first element in the array, which is `2`.

After the second pop:

`{3 |, 3, 3, <garbage>}`

and `currentValue` points to the first element, which value is `3`,

The last time, the array is unchanged (as `Q->count--` changes `Q->count`'s value to 0), so the conent is

`{| 3, 3, 3, <garbage>}` 
and `currentValue` is still pointing to a `3`.

I assume that you changed the second example to make `Queue->currentValue` an `int`.

This way, it retains the original first element (which is popped).

That makes your prints work properly in your test case.

**However,**

- Your implementation will fail if you had a `0` in your queue.
- Your implementation adds needless complexity to the `pop` operation (O(n)). It would be much better to implement a cyclic queue, with `head` and `tail`.
- Retaining a copy of the popped element in order to return it would not be my first choice. I would suggest implementing an `isEmpty()` method, check its result in the `while` loop and while the queue is not empty, simply have `pop()` return the queue advance its `head` and return the previous head element.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answers your question, the next thing to do is accept the answer :)